# How to get all firestore documents with specific id in all snapshots?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is my Flutter code for retrieve data snapshots . This return me 0 data :

```
final posts = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts');

return: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
   stream: posts.doc().collection('userPosts').where('work', isEqualto: 'something').snapshot,
   builder.......
);
```

My Firestore structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you should use a [Collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#collection-group-query) and pass the following `Stream` to the `StreamBuilder`:

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('userPosts').where('work', isEqualto: 'something').snapshots();
```

---

The `userPosts` collection group consists of **all (sub)collections** with the ID `userPost`. Note that you must create an index that supports your collection group query.